# get Selected fields in .populate() waterline-postgresql .populate('fieldName',{select:[]})

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-postgresql

select query is not working in .populate() of waterline-postgresql.

```
Model.find(query).populate(assoc.alias,{select:['field1','field2']});
```

This is not working in waterline-postgresql adapter.

Is this not supported or Am I making any mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**select** is not supported in .populate(). You can see this [github issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/919). In populate select is not working currently.

> This is feature request and it is open issue. hope in next release
>   waterline team will introduce this feature.

Comment: An update for anyone who stumbles here, the feature is meant to be supported in Waterline 0.12.0, as written in the question. https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/919#issuecomment-198458183

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no official way to do that I did some changes in order to have that. Maybe it's not the best way but it works.

```
User.find({ belongs_to: user.id })
.populate('person_id')
.exec(function findCB (err, usersFound)
{
    console.log(usersFound[0].toJSON())

    if (err)
    {
        return res.json(401, {error: err});
    }

    if (usersFound.length == 0)
    {
        return res.json(200, {message: 'No user asigned'});
    }
    else
    {
        // An array to store all the final user objects
        var asignedArray = [];

        for (index in usersFound)
        {
            var myObj = {},
                key,
                value;

            // Object in format {key: value}
            myObj['id'] = usersFound[index].id;
            myObj['fullname'] = usersFound[index].person_id.first_name + ' ' +
                                usersFound[index].person_id.second_name + ' ' +
                                usersFound[index].person_id.last_name;
            myObj['email'] = usersFound[index].email;
            myObj['job'] = usersFound[index].person_id.job;
            myObj['permission_level'] = usersFound[index].permission_level;

            // Adding the object to the main array
            asignedArray.push(myObj);
        }

        return res.json(200, {
            users: asignedArray
        });
    }
    });
```

I hope it could be useful for you.