# How can I do nested select statements in waterline

Tags: sails.js, waterline

For example I would like to do the following.

```
Model.find({select: ['id', 'fields.name']}
```

or something like this?

```
Model.find({select: ['id', {fields:['name']}]
```

Is it even possible to do nested selects in waterline?

Answer (score -1):

This question has been answered here

[get Selected fields in .populate() waterline-postgresql .populate('fieldName',{select:[]})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292018/get-selected-fields-in-populate-waterline-postgresql-populatefieldname-s)

**select** is not supported in .populate(). You can see this [github issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/919). In populate select is not working currently.

> This is feature request and it is open issue. hope in next release
>   waterline team will introduce this feature.